# raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : polynom.adb:85 index check failed

Tags: ada

I created an array like this one:

type coef_list is array(Integer range 0..50) of Integer;

But the message appears when I call this function:

t:= times(r,q);  --that multiply two polynoms.

Why? I need a dynamic array? with Ada.Vectors but how to used it? if there is any simple example to guide me, please share? Thx

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! Your post came through to me on the review queue.  It could be improved by some small edits to get the code formatting right - once you've read the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, there is also an [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page that assists with how to lay out your posts to make them as readable as possible and therefore likely to get help.

Comment: As I was writing - the post was [edited by @egilhh](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28856344/revisions) - it's worth checking out the revisions to see the edits for future reference.

Comment: In general, when you show us error messages with a line number, please let us know what lines the line numbers belong to.  You can probably figure this out from your editor or IDE, but it's hard for us to do that by looking at your post, and many posters will leave off comment lines or blank lines so that the line numbers won't be right anyway.  Adding a comment to the code in the post, like "--line 29" on the correct line, would be very helpful.

Comment: What were you trying to accomplish with `type string is new zero`?

Comment: You have replaced the original question with a completely different one, so that the existing answer makes no sense. Please rollback this last edit and ask a **new** question with your **new** problem. You (or I) can rollback an edit by clicking on the “edited” link under the question, scrolling down to the previous edit, and clicking the “rollback” link just above it.

Comment: Please, go ahead. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Ada procedures (and similar for functions) require this structure:

```
procedure Foo is
   -- declarations goes here
begin
   -- code goes here
end Foo;
```

In your code, both `polynomials` and `Main` is missing the `begin`.
You have also put declarations (`value1 : integer := 1;` etc) after `begin` in `print_polynoms`, which is illegal.

Other problems with your code:

1. You redefine the built-in type `String`.
2. The type `zero` is not defined anywhere.
3. The type `String_Pointer` is not defined anywhere.
4. This syntax makes no sense: `type Polynom is new Integer(p,p1,p2,p3,p4,q,q1,q2);` And the type `Polynom` is never used. Why declare it?
5. The variable `zero` is not defined anywhere.
6. Why have an inner procedure `Main` here? It does nothing anyway. And is never called. Probably better to move `print_polynoms` out of `Main`, as an inner function of `polynomials` directly.
7. The `polynomials` procedure does nothing, `print_polynoms` will never be called.

Also, the code you pasted seems to not be the same as the code you tried to compile. (`main` is not declared at line 9)